# Bootstrap 5 Popovers with React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add Bootstrap 5 popovers in React. I am not using any React-Bootstrap library. Per the Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/), I have added the initialization code, but I am getting these two errors. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these errors are related to restrictions of TypeScript. In order to solve the first error, I would suggest you use a `for` loop instead of using `map` like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < popoverTriggerList.length; i++) {
  const popoverTriggerEl = popoverTriggerList[i];
  new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
}
```

In order to solve the second error, I would suggest you declare a `bootstrap` variable like:

```
declare var bootstrap: any;
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-ntf8bi?file=/src/App.tsx) (*bootstrap included by cdn*) or [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-with-import-pvgn1v?file=/src/App.tsx) (*bootstrap included by npm*) for a live working examples of these usages.

Comment: The `for` loop resolved the first issue,thank you. But I'm now getting a run time error `Signup2.tsx:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined`.

Comment: That's probably because you didn't add bootstrap bundle to your app. You need to add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in `head` section of the `public/index.html` file. You can see it in the sandbox.

Comment: In my `index.tsx` file I have `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';`

Comment: You can also look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-with-import-pvgn1v?file=/src/App.tsx) to see example of bootstrap included by npm. I have also updated the answer to show both examples.